# Adding array with MySQL inside a Multidimentional Array

Tags: php, dynamic, multidimensional-array

I am creating a json multidimentional Array for use in my jquery mobile panel and it works like a charm, but...

Now I want to make some af the panel list dynamic and get some af the data from database and I don't know how to do this?

Here is my static array:

```
$panels = array(
        array('list' => '<li><a href="../index.html">Start</a></li>'),
        array('list' => '<li><a href="#">My profile</a></li>'),
        array('list' => '<li><a href="#">Statistics</a></li>'),
        array('list' => '<li data-role="list-divider">My groups</li>'),
        array('list' => '<li><a href="pages/grouppage.html?groupid=1" rel="external">My first group</a></li> '),
        array('list' => '<li><a href="pages/grouppage.html?groupid=5" rel="external">I am testing again</a></li> '));
```

As you can see, my last 2 lists are the same and should come from my database depending on which user it is, but I don't know how to do this?

Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: What is your question? How to use a MySQL query?

Comment: Did you already designed a database structure. Its not clear what you already tried or what your question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$database_data = "some data from database";
$data = array('list'=>$database_data);
$panels[] = $data ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you and write your query as per the requirement..

```
 while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $arr[] = array(
                'list' => '<li><a href='" . $r['page_url'] . "'>" . $r['page_name'] . "</a></li>'
            );
 }
```